# Access to fetch at 'myUrl' from origin 'myLocalHost' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: react-native, asp.net-core, cors, request-headers

I use fetch API on client side and I get this error:

**Access to Fetch at 'myUrl' from origin 'mylocalhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

with react-native I can get the response well, but when I want to use the request in react-js I get this error!

on backend side(asp.net core 2.1): 
I add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in header, based on microsoft document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1

on startup:

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options => {
                options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowClientOrigin"));
            });
```

```
 services.AddCors((cors)=>
            {
                cors.AddPolicy("AllowClientOrigin", policy => 
                policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials());
            });
```

```
app.UseCors("AllowClientOrigin");
```

and for the controllers:

```
[EnableCors("AllowClientOrigin")]
```

but the problem is still there!

Comment: @ZhiLv thanks for your comment, How can I add it in request header ? I add some code in my fetch api : ` mode:'cors', credentials:'include'  ` ,is there any thing else that I should do on client side?

Comment: After researching, it seems that specifying AllowAnyOrigin and AllowCredentials is an insecure configuration and can result in cross-site request forgery. The CORS service returns an invalid CORS response when an app is configured with both methods. So, try to use the WithOrigins method to add the allowed Origins, code as below:`services.AddCors((cors) => {cors.AddPolicy("AllowClientOrigin", policy => policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44351").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());});`.

Comment: To learn more about the preflight request, see [Preflight requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#preflight-requests).